# Laravel 5.5 BroadcastException in PusherBroadcaster.php (line 106)

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, pusher

I have no clue why i am getting **BroadcastException
in PusherBroadcaster.php (line 106)** I am using Laravel 5.5 and Vue 2.0. I have tried all possible way but no luck. Badly need help. I have done :

**.env**

```
PUSHER_APP_ID=403348
PUSHER_APP_KEY=691857f3d69337b25cf9
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=f36dc5c5114067449338
```

**broadcasting.php**

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => 'us2',
                'encrypted' => true
            ],
        ],
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import VueAutosize from 'vue-autosize';
import axios from 'axios';
import Form from './utilities/Form';
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';


window.Vue = Vue;


window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.use(VueAutosize)

window.axios = axios;
window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};

window.Form = Form;

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: '691857f3d69337b25cf9',
    cluster: 'us2',
    encrypted: true,
});
```

**NotificationEvent.php**

```
class NotificationEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('notifications');
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';
import router from './routes'; 

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,

    created() {
        Echo.channel('notifications')
            .listen('NotificationEvent', (e) => {
                alert('adada');
            });
    }
});
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('notification', function() {
    event(new NotificationEvent());
});
```

it shows when try **/notification**  :

[image]

Comment: this is known issue.. check.. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/16478

Comment: @ZaheerAttar Thanks for reply. i tried with the solution they suggested on this link. bt no luck. i have downlaoded another github project with laravel 5.4 which is working. But when i am applying on my own project i am getting this issue. I have no clue what wrong i am doing ..

Comment: Do you set the broadcasting route in `routes/channels.php` file?
Did you read the official [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/broadcasting) about the broadcasting?

Answer (score 0):

Pusher requires SSL to work. Put encrypted => false in your Broadcasting.php for localhost development and try. Worked for me...